# Rails console in sandbox mode not reverting db on exit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using sandbox mode for querying as: rails console --sandbox
.but it is not reverting current make changes on exit.
I am using rails version: Rails 4.1.6
Ruby version: ruby 2.0.0p353
Is it a bug with rails or ruby version?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably right. There seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9513) with rails 4.

Looks like there may be a fix commit at the bottom of that thread.